# Field in Model Not Recognized For Migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-imagekit

In my UserProfile model, I just added django-imagekit and the thumbnail field here to create thumbnails for me, but when i run ./manage.py makemigrations, django says that there are no changes detected, and thumbnail field is not added to the database.

Here is my code. I am using Python 3.4 and Django 1.7:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
        return '/'.join([instance.user_auth.email, filename])

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user_auth = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Phone number")
    birth_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of Birth", null=True, blank=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('N', 'Not Specified'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=False, default='N', verbose_name='Gender')
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name,
                            width_field="width_field",
                            height_field="height_field",
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            verbose_name="Profile Picture"
                           )
    height_field = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    width_field = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='pic',
                                   processors=[ResizeToFill(120,120)],
                                   format='JPEG',
                                   options={'quality': 60})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's technically not a field that is written to the database. So you don't have to make any migration for whatever you're using (SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc). When you access your `UserProfile.thumbnail` it will create the image for you right then and there based on the data from the pic ImageField.

From the [documentation](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

> ImageSpecFields, on the other hand, are virtual—they add no fields to
>   your database and don’t require a database. This is handy for a lot of
>   reasons, but it means that the path to the image file needs to be
>   programmatically constructed based on the source image and the spec.

If you want it to generate the thumbnail and save it then you should be using `ProcessedImageField`

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should have read the documentation more closely.